# Custom Workflow status?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Hi
I have a SPD workflow , it works like this
 If form is incomplete ,stop the workflow.
If form is complete , start the approval workflow.
When the form is incomplete ,user just save the form in the form library , the workflow stats then terminates , it will show status complete. It is confusing to users. Ideally the workflow should not start when user save the incomplete form. However , it seems to hard to do it.
So I just like to create a custom state ,maybe NEW ,   If form is incomplete, set it to New.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use two different fields.

The one you already have is the "technical status" of the workflow (in progress, complete), that only you - the designer - need to care about.

Then you'll have a separate field for the "business status", where you can define your own steps or even drop plain text (for rexample: "incomplete form, the xxx field is missing").

Comment: This solves the user's problem but not the question!

Comment: @BGM sometimes solving a problem starts by acknoledging that you are not asking the right question (what we call a xy problem).

Comment: I was hinting that perhaps the OP should change the title.  Maybe that was a bit too subtle..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the action '**Wait for**' in which you can mention any field that has to be filled by the user at last. So you can be sure that workflow will start only when value us filled in that field.