# Editing Workflow Status Default value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, status

I have Leave Form created in InfoPath and Published it to SharePoint 2013
I applied a simple OOTB Workflow in my form.

I just want to ask if possible to edit the default value of Workflow Status?

Let say i want to make it:
   Approved = 1
   Rejected = 2
   In Progress = 3

Any idea is really appreciated. Hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to set workflow status.
Please use **Set Workflow Status** action in SharePoint Designer. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
 
Check also these [guidelines](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-actions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6?CorrelationId=bd91620f-3cd1-4d04-88c6-d53a45bf70f8&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010376961) for setting the status and its limitations.

If you are running approval workflow, you can use the following values:
Status  Value
Not Started 0
Failed on Start 1
In Progress 2
Error Occurred  3
Canceled    4
Completed   5
Failed on Start(Retrying)   6
Error Occurred (Retrying)   7
Canceled    15
Approved    16
Rejected    17


From: http://www.officeandbusiness.be/2010/05/17/sharepoint-workflow-status-how-to-use-the-workflow-status-in-a-workflow-or-a-view/

You can also create a separate column: [Custom Workflow status?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/custom-workflow-status)

Another way is to use Visual Studio: http://www.schaeflein.net/setting-workflow-status-in-visual-studio-and-sharepoint-designer/
http://sharepoint.ginni.me/2010/01/setting-workflow-status-to-custom.html